# Python 3 Try Except Error Handling With Missing Arguments in Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, exception, try-except

I am having trouble dealing with exceptions where the incorrect number of arguments are given when a function is called.

Here's a simplified example:

```
def func(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 + arg2

func(46)
```

When the function is called without the correct number of arguments, the following error message is generated:

```
TypeError: func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg2'
```

I have tried to add a try, except to handle this exception, as follows, but it does not work:

```
def func(arg1, arg2):
    try:
        return arg1 + arg2
    except:
        return 'Incorrect input'
```

The function still generates the error message, rather than the 'Incorrect input' statement.

How can I have the function return the message 'Incorrect input' when the wrong number of arguments are given when the function is called?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want that? The developer should be able to understand the given error message just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The exception happens upon the function call, before entering func so you did not manage to catch it:

```
def func(arg1, arg2):
        return arg1 + arg2

try:
    func(46)
except TypeError:
    print('Incorrect input')
```

Note the error message you received state it is 'TypeError' so you should catch only this kind of error.